# Activate only 2 items in a list

Tags: javascript, html, class

I have a container in which there are 4 buttons. What I want is that if I select one of them it gets activated, I click second one it gets activated, but if I click third one, then the first one should get deactivated such that I'm only left with second and third one activated.

```
<div class="container">
    <a id="01-01-2019.30-06-2019" onclick= {setDate1} class="myButton">01-01-2019___30-06-2019</a>
    <a id="01-07-2019.31-12-2019" onclick= {setDate2} class="myButton">01-07-2019___31-12-2019</a>
    <a id="01-01-2020.30-06-2020" onclick= {setDate3} class="myButton">01-01-2020___30-06-2020</a>
    <a id="01-07-2020.31-12-2020" onclick= {setDate4} class="myButton">01-07-2020___31-12-2020</a>
</div>

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myButton");
var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

if(current.length > 2){

  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");

}else{
  this.className += " active";
}

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  };
}
```

this is what I have tried so far but I have no clue what to do next. Any sugessions ?

Comment: Is the JS part inside a function? That `for` has no sense. For adding and removing class use classList. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp). You should use other type of `id` in buttons. (Like btn_1, btn_2 if you want)

Comment: Can you implement an enqueue system?

If the number of items is < 2 , you add the new one activated.  If it is > 2 you deactivate the first one and add to the queue the new one activated.  Its a generic solution, because in the future you only need change the number 2 and this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might look like a lot, but it's very extensible and offers the ability to allow *n*-number of selections.

Just add a data attribute with the time the button was clicked and age off the oldest one, if you have too many selected.

The third example is "strict", meaning, you MUST remove a selection to select another, if you reached the limit. In addition, the configuration comes from the data attributes in the DOM. The HTML attributes supersede any JS config.

```js
const main = () => {
  new ButtonGroup('.btn-group-1')
  new ButtonGroup('.btn-group-2', { maxActive: 2 })       // Max of 2
  new ButtonGroup(document.querySelector('.btn-group-3')) // HTML-driven
}

class UIComponent {
  constructor(target) {
    if (typeof target === 'string' && target !== '') {
      target = document.querySelector(target)
    }
    if (target == null) {
      throw new Error('target was not declared')
    }
    this.reference = target
  }

  /** @protected */
  __applyOptions(options, defaults) {
    return Object.assign({}, defaults || {}, options, this.reference.dataset)
  }

  /** @protected */
  __children(selector) {
    return [...this.reference.querySelectorAll(selector)]
  }

  /** @protected */
  __addListeners(selector, eventName, listener) {
    this.__children(selector).forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener(eventName, e => listener(e))
    })
  }
}

class ButtonGroup extends UIComponent {
  constructor(target, options) {
    super(target)

    let opts = this.__applyOptions(options, ButtonGroup.defaultOptions)

    this.activeClass = opts.activeClass
    this.maxActive = opts.maxActive
    this.strict = opts.modeStrict

    this.__addListeners('button', 'click', e => this.__toggleState(e.target))
  }

  /** @public */
  activeCount() {
    return this.__activeButtons().length
  }

  /** @private */
  __activeButtons() {
    return this.__children(`button.${this.activeClass}`)
  }

  /** @private */
  __additionAllowed() {
    return this.activeCount() < this.maxActive
  }

  /** @private */
  __tooManyActive() {
    return this.activeCount() > this.maxActive
  }

  /** @private */
  __toggleState(btn) {
    if (btn.classList.contains(this.activeClass)) {
      delete btn.dataset.lastClicked
      btn.classList.remove(this.activeClass)
    } else {
      if (!this.strict || (this.strict && this.__additionAllowed())) {
        if (!this.strict) {
          btn.dataset.lastClicked = new Date().getTime()
        }
        btn.classList.add(this.activeClass)
      }
    }
    this.__invalidate()
  }

  /** @private */
  __invalidate() {
    if (!this.strict && this.__tooManyActive()) {
      let oldestButton = this.__oldestButton()
      delete oldestButton.dataset.lastClicked
      oldestButton.classList.remove(this.activeClass)
    }
  }

  /** @private */
  __oldestButton() {
    return this.__activeButtons()
      .sort((a, b) => b.dataset.lastClicked - a.dataset.lastClicked)
      .pop()
  }
}

ButtonGroup.defaultOptions = {
  activeClass: 'active',
  maxActive: 1,
  modeStrict: false
}

main()
```

```css
:root {
  --bg: #111;
  --fg: #FFF;
  --btn-bg: #333;
  --btn-fg: #FFF;
  --btn-border-color: #666;
  --btn-active-bg: #555;
  --btn-active-fg: #AAA;
  --btn-active-border-color: #DD0;
}

body {
  background: var(--bg);
  color: var(--fg);
}

.btn-group {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 1.33em;
}

.btn-group button {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  color: var(--btn-fg);
  background: var(--btn-bg);
  border: 2px outset var(--btn-border-color);
}

.btn-group button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-group button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-group button.active {
  color: var(--btn-active-fg);
  background: var(--btn-active-bg);
  border: 2px inset var(--btn-border-color);
}

.btn-group .example-no {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-1">
  <span class="example-no">1</span>
  <button>Item A</button>
  <button>Item B</button>
  <button>Item C</button>
  <button>Item D</button>
  <button>Item E</button>
  <button>Item F</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-2">
  <span class="example-no">2</span>
  <button>Item A</button>
  <button>Item B</button>
  <button>Item C</button>
  <button>Item D</button>
  <button>Item E</button>
  <button>Item F</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-3" data-mode-strict="true" data-max-active="3">
  <span class="example-no">3</span>
  <button>Item A</button>
  <button>Item B</button>
  <button>Item C</button>
  <button>Item D</button>
  <button>Item E</button>
  <button>Item F</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array of elements and remove unwanted parts.

```js
function clickButton(element) {
    let index = buttons.indexOf(element);
    if (index !== -1) {
        element.className = element.className.replace(" active", "");
        buttons.splice(index, 1);
        return;
    }
    while (buttons.length > 1) {
        let [temp] = buttons.splice(0, 1);
        temp.className = temp.className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    buttons.push(element);
    element.className += " active";
}

var buttons = [];
```

```css
.myButton { border: none; outline: none; padding: 10px 16px; background-color: #f1f1f1; cursor: pointer; }
.myButton.active, .myButton:hover { background-color: #666; color: white; }
```

```html
<button id="01-01-2019.30-06-2019" onclick="clickButton(this)" class="myButton">01-01-2019___30-06-2019</button>
<button id="01-07-2019.31-12-2019" onclick="clickButton(this)" class="myButton">01-07-2019___31-12-2019</button>
<button id="01-01-2020.30-06-2020" onclick="clickButton(this)" class="myButton">01-01-2020___30-06-2020</button>
<button id="01-07-2020.31-12-2020" onclick="clickButton(this)" class="myButton">01-07-2020___31-12-2020</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always 2 how about a simple swap of variables?

```js
var btn1=""; var btn2="";

function actBtn(e){
 if(e != btn1 && e != btn2){
  if(btn1){ btn1.style.backgroundColor = ''; }
  e.style.backgroundColor = '#0f0';
  btn1 = btn2;
  btn2 = e;
 }
}
```

```html
<button id="01-01-2019.30-06-2019" onclick="actBtn(this)" class="myButton">01-01-2019___30-06-2019</button>
<button id="01-07-2019.31-12-2019" onclick="actBtn(this)" class="myButton">01-07-2019___31-12-2019</button>
<button id="01-01-2020.30-06-2020" onclick="actBtn(this)" class="myButton">01-01-2020___30-06-2020</button>
<button id="01-07-2020.31-12-2020" onclick="actBtn(this)" class="myButton">01-07-2020___31-12-2020</button>
```